# Play 2.1.0 + Apache 2.2 Reverse proxy => 502 proxy error when idle

Tags: apache, angularjs, playframework-2.1, reverse-proxy

### Config

We have a play 2.1.0 with angularjs setup in a production mode. 
We have reverse proxy load balancer setup with apache 2.2 something like mentioned in here
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HTTPServer
This whole app is running in an iframe inside navigated from a jboss application.

### Problem

Most of the time it works and sometimes when the connection is left idle for 2/3 hours, untouched, no one hit the reverse proxy url to load the jboss/play, then we are getting the `502 proxy error` in the iframe content after a few mins wait.

Play receives the request, but somehow decides not to respond at all. This occurs only for the first time or couple of time after the wakeup. Then when we refresh the page play receives the request and responds it properly.

### Tried

We get a tcpdump on the play port and it we have got all the requests being received, but no response sent from play for the failed scenario. Whereas the same request got responded by play subsequent times.
`X-Forwarded-For: ,X-Forwarded-Host:  X-Forwarded-Server: .. Connection: Keep-Alive`  - all these headers are being sent in the lost response tcpdump.

Tried KeepAlive, with timeouts in the proxy server, not much help. Why the play didn't respond for the initial connections after idle state, is there any conf we can set to keep it alive?

### Workaround

Polling the play server url constantly every half an hour from the same server makes this issue not reproducible.

Still any help/suggestions would be really appreciated to fix this issue..

Comment: Does the Play app run on "your" server or is it hosted on something like CloudBees or Heroku?

Comment: It runs on our own server, we havent gone that far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem myself. Approaches like the answers mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/386321/deploying-play-2-0-application-on-an-apache-server-with-a-reverse-proxy) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/185894/proxy-error-502-reason-error-reading-from-remote-server-with-apache-2-2-3-de) did not change anything.
I then decided to go for [nginx](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer) again which I have been using with Play applications before. [The setup is to be found here.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HTTPServer) Since then the problem is gone.